# How to implement search through all iOS application (not just one table)? Is there any framework for that kind of search?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, search

I'm developing iOS application, and I need to implement Search which will return result of search but through all application not just from table view. Can I somehow get all strings in application that are displayed to user and iterate through them comparing every one with string that user entered for search? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Put all the strings into a global array and you can iterate through them

Answer (score 0):

Put all strings that your app can show in database (sqlite), core data, in some file or in a global array and then search through it.

Comment: So I just iterate through all views in view controllers. collect all strings from them and save in some global variable? For example, uilalbels, uitextviews, uibuttons etc, and collect their strings...

Comment: You can create a database table/core data table/file/global array of all static strings of the application and it can be populated at application start (in a secondary thread) and for dynamic strings you can update your string store as and when you get those strings. This way you don't need to iterate on your views and subviews each and every time

Comment: I will try that, I think it's a good solution... I had something similar on my mind with local database, and filling it when app starts with static strings, but i needed second opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate through all the controllers. Create a singleton class and store all the strings that you want to be included in the search into that class as and when they are being displayed.

How to do that though depends on whether you want the search results to be actionable or not, an a few other factors.

Comment: This is actually the correct approach. A DataBase would just be needed if you need to maintain the array of Strings between sessions (closing/opening the app).

Comment: No, I do not need to maintain array... Data is always the same. Thanks... ;)